# Forcing code to wait for object instantiation before continuing

Tags: swift, escaping, closures, core-location

I've written a class, UserLocation (below), which uses CoreLocation to get the user's current place (string) & latitude and longitude (also a string "lat,long" for passing to APIs).

My code below works, but when I initialize the class, the rest of my code doesn't wait for the init to finish before moving on, so I miss the opportunity to assign the location-related values that I'm trying to retrieve.

Is this a sound approach (or should I think about some other more "MVC" organization), and if it is, how can I get my code to wait for the initialization (with location find & reverse geocoding) to finish before moving on. Is there a way to put the code below the initialization into some sort of @escaping closure that's specified in the class's init?  I'm new to swift so thanks for your kind advice.

In ViewController.swift's viewDidAppear():

```
let userLocation = UserLocation() // initializes properly but code below doesn't wait.
locationsArray[0].name = userLocation.place
locationsArray[0].coordinates = userLocation.coordinates
```

And my UserLocation.swift class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class UserLocation {
    var place = ""
    var coordinates = ""

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!

    init() {
        returnResults()
    }

    func returnResults () {
        getUserLocation { placemark in
            if placemark != nil {
                self.place = (placemark?.name)!
                self.coordinates = "\((placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude)!),\((placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)"
            } else {
                print("Error retrieving placemark")
            }
        }
    }

    func getUserLocation(completion: @escaping (CLPlacemark?) -> ()) {
        var placemark: CLPlacemark?

        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() 

        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse ||
            CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways) {
            currentLocation = locationManager.location

            let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
            geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    print("Error getting location: \(error)")
                    placemark = nil
                } else {
                    placemark = placemarks?.first
                }
                completion(placemark)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension CLPlacemark {
    var cityState: String {
        var result = ""
        switch (self.locality, self.administrativeArea, self.country) {
        case (.some, .some, .some("United States")):
            result = "\(locality!), \(administrativeArea!)"
        case (.some, _ , .some):
            result = "\(locality!), \(country!)"
        default:
            result = name ?? "Location Unknown"
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not necessarily a Swift issue. Your problem is caused by the fact that `returnResults` executes the variables setup in an async manner because it calls an async function - `getUserLocation`, which is async as `reverseGeocodeLocation` is async (this is how CoreLocation works - you don't get the location synchronously, but in a callback).

You don't want to wait for `returnResults` to execute the callback, as this would mean blocking the main thread while `CoreLocation` initializes and tries to determine the location. Instead you should follow the async pattern by using a completion block that `returnResults` can use to signal the completion of the location retrieval.

An example for the above would be:

```
class UserLocation {
    var place = ""
    var coordinates = ""

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!

    init() {
       // don't call anymore from here, let the clients ask for the locations 
    }

    // This was renamed from returnResults to a more meaningful name
    // Using the Bool in the completion to signal the success/failure
    // of the location retrieval
    func updateLocations(withCompletion completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        getUserLocation { placemark in
            if placemark != nil {
                self.place = (placemark?.name)!
                self.coordinates = "\((placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude)!),\((placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)"
                completion(true)
            } else {
                print("Error retrieving placemark")
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
...
```

You can then modify the called code to something like this:

```
let userLocation = UserLocation()
userLocation.updateLocations { success in
    guard success else { return }
    locationsArray[0].name = userLocation.place
    locationsArray[0].coordinates = userLocation.coordinates
}
```

You don't block the main thread, and you execute the appropriate code when the location is available.